# Link between Navis and Model Coordination is not working properly, Glue Classic does work

Tags: autodesk-forge

With modelcoordination we experience a slowdown in the application Navisworks when accessing properties.

Our app searches for properties and creates searchsets automated to save time. We use the Navisworks API to do so using the functionality of:
ModelItemCollection searchResults = s.FindAll(Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application.ActiveDocument, true);

We redefine "s" and "searchResults" foreach needed searchset and save the search as SavedItem (SearchSet).

Because we create a lot of SearchSets using this method the slowdown is more noticeable.

This action in a model from BIM 360 Glue (Classic) takes up to 10 seconds, where the same model in Model Coordination (next gen) takes more than 30 minutes.

The slowdown is visible unregarding our app. Also when clicking on properties in the selection tree, or in SearchSets the slowdown occurs.

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait. So if I understand correctly ,running the same Navisworks code with  the models from Model Coordination module (next gen), it will take long time, while if the same models from Glue, it will be very quick If yes, we may need to test it directly. Is it possible to add me to the project?  xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com . And also the test code of Navisworks. Due to holiday at my side, I may be responding a little slow, while I will also post the question with our engineer team if any colleague could shed a light. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The comments from the engineer team was: The model in Model Coordination of BIM360 will be translated to SVF (typically for being loaded in browser based Forge Viewer, and for providing the metadata of the model).  At Navisworks side, it currently supports properties for SVF models. Search API was affected by the converted properties. The issue was logged by the two internal tickets at NW-56714 and NW-56713. The idea is to allow "Convert Properties" defaulting to "Off" so as not to break any Search Sets that customers may have set up.

Comment: but it would be still helpful if you could provide an isolated test case and model for us to verify the behavior. Thank you